# Vuex - crear objeto en la Data( ) del Component con info que viene del Getter

Tags: javascript, vuex, component, store

Soy nueva en Vue. Necesito crear un objeto llamado `articulo` en un Componente.
La información para poder crear ese objeto viene del Store ( a través del Getter `obtenerArticuloPorId`)
Sé que el Componente está recibiendo esa información correctamente ya que puedo verlo, pero no sé como crear un nuevo objeto en el Data() del Componente con esos datos que vienen del Getter.

**Component.js**

````
```<div class="popup" v-if="obtenerArticuloPorId">
    <div>
      <h2>{{ obtenerArticuloPorId?.nombre }}</h2>
      <p>{{ obtenerArticuloPorId?.precio }}<span>$</span></p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </template>

 <script>
  import {mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex'

  export default {
  data(){
    return {
       articulo: {
          nombre: this.obtenerArticuloPorId.nombre,
          precio: this.obtenerArticuloPorId.precio
       }
    }

  },
  methods:{
    ...mapActions(['obtenerId']),
    ...mapActions(['setAgregarCarrito'])
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['obtenerArticuloPorId'])
  }

 }
</script>```
````

Comment: No entiendo que queres hacer.. tu codigo ya recibe los datos de ese objeto... que otra cosa queres hacer?

Comment: Quiero crear un nuevo objeto con informacion que viene del getter y añadir otras propiedades. Sé que no es necesario que lo haga para poder reenviar los datos a traves de una funcion, pero me gustaría saber si es posible hacerlo.

Comment: Si, podes crear un nuevo objeto... solo tenes que definirlo y crearlo en el mount o en una funcion en particular....

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias, funcionó perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

El helper **mapGetters** puede ser invocado de dos maneras:

- La que estás usando tú, por medio de un array:

  ...mapGetters(['obtenerArticuloPorId'])

En cuyo caso se almazanerá lo que te devuelve la *store* en una variable llamada **obtenerArticuloPorId**.

- O pasándole un objeto. En cuyo caso podrás elegir el nombre de la variable en la que almacenar lo que obtengas de la **store**:

  ...mapGetters({ articulo: 'obtenerArticuloPorId' })

Esta segunda manera parece ser la que estás buscando.

**Referencia:** [mapGetters Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper)